# Rails not redirecting within a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently following a tutorial on Rails 4 but for an unknown reason, I can't get the sample working (*Rails 4 in Action, chapter 7*). At some point, I created a require_signin! method and a current_user one inside application_controller.rb. They look like this:

```
private

  def require_signin!

    if current_user.nil?
      flash[:error] = "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      redirect_to signin_url

    end

  end
  helper_method :require_signin!

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

So far, so good. When I add a before_action :require_signin! at the top of a controller, it redirects correctly to the sign in page if user is null or if session[:user_id] is null.

Then, I add a new method below require_signin! that is named authorize_admin!. I have an admin boolean field in my user model. The method looks like this:

```
def authorize_admin!
    require_signin!

    unless current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You must be an admin to do that."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

At the top of one of my controllers, I added:

```
before_action :authorize_admin!
```

**The issue is this**: if I'm signed in as a non-admin user, I get properly redirected to root_path. If I'm not signed in at all, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass


----  
    require_signin!

        **unless current_user.admin?**
          flash[:alert] = "You must be an admin to do that."
          redirect_to root_path
        end
----
```

For some reason, I don't get redirected to the sign in page when the method enters the require_signin! method. I know it properly enters the method as I placed a 'fail' inside it to check if it was called.

Thanks for your help, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `unless current_user.admin?` to

```
if current_user && !current_user.admin?
```

to ensure that user signed in.

Comment: I did try that. There are two issues with this: 1) I get error "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action" and 2) even if it worked, the user wouldn't get redirected to the sign in page.

Comment: Your updated answer works! Thank you! Still, I don't understand why when entering "require_signin!" the redirect_to is not fired when the user is not signed in and why the method continues to execute.